# Insert array of objects as property into neo4j

Tags: arrays, neo4j, query-performance

I am trying to insert array of objects as property to node. I tried

```
MERGE (ss:Label1 {sId: 12345})
  ON MATCH SET ss.id = 14770746012, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [{id: 24, status: 0}]
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 14770746012, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [{id: 24, status: 0}]
```

If run I am getting follwing error::

```
Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
```

What to even I tried with nested array, that gave me same error as above.

I studied in Neo4j documentation that Neo4j can't support 'Nesting of property values'

How to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 3):

As Neo4j not support hierarchical properties, one of the ways to solve this problem - to create additional nodes:

```
MERGE (ss:Label1 {sId: 12345, id: 14770746012, setC: 1 })
MERGE (nl:Props:nlProp {id: 24, status: 0})
MERGE (ss)-[:hasProps]->(nl)
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by stdob--, you can create additional nodes if your need to use those properties in queries (for filtering, aggregation, etc.).

If however, you just want to write and read the data but not act on it in queries, you can serialize it, for example as JSON:

```
MERGE (ss:Label1 {sId: 12345})
  ON MATCH SET ss.id = 14770746012, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = ["{\"id\": 24, \"status\": 0}"]
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 14770746012, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = ["{\"id\": 24, \"status\": 0}"]
```

Comment: The [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) procedure `apoc.convert.toJson` can be used to do the JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split up the `nl` collection into a separate collection for each element property. For example:

```
MERGE (ss:Label1 {sId: 12345})
SET ss.id = 14770746012, ss.setC = 1, ss.nl_ids = [24], ss.nl_statuses: [0];
```

Corresponding `nl_ids` and `nl_statuses` values have the same index.

*Aside: since your `ON MATCH SET ...` and `ON CREATE SET ...` actions are exactly the same, I just combined them into a single `SET ...` clause.*